# Delete all siblings to the right but not to the left JQUERY JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a breadcrumb and a button is added within a DIV as you go deep in the folders like:

```
<div id='breadcrumb-wrapper'><button id='uniqueId1'>FolderName1</button><button id='uniqueId2'>FolderName2</button><button id='uniqueId3'>FolderName3</button><button id='uniqueId4'>FolderName4</button></div>
```

Every button goes to its patch and I need to delete all the siblings to its right but not to its left when the user click it, if I use something like:

```
$('#breadcrumb-wrapper').nextAll('#uniqueId3').remove();
```

All siblings plus ALL elements go away from that node and that's not the idea. If I use something like:

```
$('#uniqueId3').siblings().remove();
```

All siblings including the first and the second one go away which as well It's not what I need to do, so how could I achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nextAll` on the element itself, not on the parent:

```js
$('#uniqueId3').nextAll().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='breadcrumb-wrapper'>
  <button id='uniqueId1'>FolderName1</button>
  <button id='uniqueId2'>FolderName2</button>
  <button id='uniqueId3'>FolderName3</button>
  <button id='uniqueId4'>FolderName4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, the method does work with itself as well, great to learn something. Thank you very much, it did it.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try "[Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)"

In your case `$('#uniqueId3 ~ button').remove()` should work.

Comment: Yep, this seems like the way to go, I just have semantically doubt, since this is dynamically build the function receive a btn object and I’m not quite sure how to wright it right:  $(btn.id' ~ button').remove() :/

Comment: @Diego `$('#' + CSS.escape(btn.id) + ' ~ *')`, assuming `btn` has an ID. You don't need `CSS.escape` if the ID is a [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: $('#' + btn.id + ' ~ button').remove().. same as how you build any dynamic jquery selector.

Comment: Thanks Oriol, for mentioning CSS.escape.

Comment: Both answers do the job, I'm going to stick with nextAll() since I have some code under this line. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#breadcrumb-wrapper button").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll().remove();
});
```

with this structure, you can do it like this, but if have more button that you don't want to remove then provide same class to all button which you wish  to remove